# jsonp cross domain request response gives null while parsing

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I tried to make a cross domain request using jquery. this is how client side will looks like,

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://www.xserver.com/xdomainhandler.php",
        processData: true,
        data: {
            type:"gotohell"
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            myglob=data;
            var repo=JSON.parse(myglob);
            alert(repo.type);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('ends up in error state');

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and the server page code which receives this request will look like this:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));
header('Content-type: application/json');
session_cache_limiter('nocache');

$arr = array ('response'=>'success','comment'=>'test comment here','type'=>$_GET['type']);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

But when i completed the request/response process i got nothing in the 'repo' variable. i checked the response using firebug and it shows response like,

`{"response":"success","comment":"test comment here","type":"gotohell"}`

also i checked **myglob** variable in DOM panel of firebug it shows,

```
Object { response="success", comment="test comment here", type="gotohell"}
```

but when i parsed the myglob to repo, it shows nothing.. where i'm going wrong. can somebody help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to parse it as jQuery parses it for yo so avoid

```
        var repo=JSON.parse(myglob);
```

and just call

```
  alert(data.type);
```

Comment: Thanks, Its worked. i got it,so if we set datatype as json it will automatically get parsed right?

Comment: @Sekar yes, and if you don't set the dataType jQuery will try to guess it from the headers and if it guess it's a json it will parse it, so you should never parse the response

Answer (score 2):

Because you supplied `dataType: 'json'` jQuery will already have parsed the response - parsing it again will cause errors. Remove the following line:

```
var repo = JSON.parse(myglob);
```